# Which assert method I can use check whether the elements in the array are unique?

Tags: junit

I have an integer array of 1000 elements. Which assert method I can use to check whether the elements in the array are unique?

Comment: Rather than using an Integer array, would it not make more sense to use a Set http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html of integers? Then you know the values are always going to be unique?

Answer (score 3):

```
 Set<?> mySet = Sets.newHashSet(myArray);
 Assert.assertEquals(mySet.size(), myArray.length);
```

I used Guava's [Sets](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newHashSet%28E...%29) class as a conventience, but you could also just add each element

```
 Set<?> mySet = new HashSet<?>();
 mySet.addAll(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

Comment: If you need to do this a lot, I'd recommend making a Hamcrest matcher to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, rather than using an Integer array, would it not make more sense to use a Set http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html of integers?  Then you know the values are always going to be unique?

> public interface Set extends Collection A collection that
>   contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of
>   elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null
>   element. As implied by its name, this interface models the
>   mathematical set abstraction.